# Unblock signals using standard utilities

Tags: bash, signals

How can I unblock signals in bash using standard utilities?

In the past few weeks, I've noticed shells on macos hanging (eg, `yes | head` does not terminate).  Digging in, it appears that all new shells I create are blocking a fairly large set of signals. (So, in the previous example, `yes` is blocking SIGPIPE.  Cautionary tale to tool writers; check the return value of `write`, `printf`, etc).

This behavior is a bit annoying, but now that I know the problem it is easy to fix.  But not quite easy enough.  `trap` doesn't seem to do the trick (I'm using bash).  What can I add to my bash startups to clear the set of blocked signals using standard utilities?  I have added the following, and it feels terribly kludgy:

```
if { ! show-mask && which unblock; } > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        exec unblock bash
fi
```

where show-mask and unblock are built from:

```
$ cat show-mask.c 
/* Show the current set of blocked signals */    
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct sigaction act = {{0}};
        sigset_t old;

        if(sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, NULL, &old)) {
                perror("sigprocmask");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("mask: %x\n", old);

        return !!old;
}
$ cat unblock.c
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void
set_default(struct sigaction *act, int s)
{
        if(sigaction(s, act, NULL)) {
                perror("sigaction");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct sigaction act = {{0}};
        sigset_t new;

        sigemptyset(&new);

        if(sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &new, NULL)) {
                perror("sigprocmask");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        set_default(&act, SIGPIPE);
        set_default(&act, SIGINT);
        set_default(&act, SIGTERM);

        execvp(argv[1], argv+1);

        perror("execlp");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Was this behavior always this way?  What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: No, behavior is new. I suspect related to the tmux session I'm running; I suspect for some reason the tmux client is blocking the signals and that disposition is getting inherited by new shells.

Comment: Is `sigset_t` really an `int` on MacOS? It certainly is __not__ on Linux and FreeBSD.